# dropdown value within get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, get

I am new to nodejs and am trying to find a way to get the dropdown value on get request. Currently I have below code which asynchronously passes the value from my database connection (Dashboard module) into the html dropdown in scripttest.html via select parameter.

Is it possible to get the value user has selected so I can query the data in my other module within the same get request? I tried using req.body but it is returning undefined.

```
const Dashboard = require('./Dashboard.js');
 this.router.get("/script_test", (req, res) => {
   (async() => {
                try {
                Dashboard.PopulateSnapShotDropdown().
                            then(result => res.render(path.join(__dirname,"client","scripttest.html"), {select: result}));
                } catch(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                };
})();
   //var user_input = req.body.Snapshotdate;
});
```

Comment: GET requests have no request body. Either pass the user selection in a query parameter or use a POST request

Comment: @Phil Could you please provide me an example/resource for 'Either pass the user selection in a query parameter'? I am trying to see if there is anyway to do it without using POST